# Excel VBA "unhide rows" changes the order of ranges while unhiding

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am using following macro to unhide rows step by step by pressing the button. However it occasionally changes the order of my ranges. So sometimes it unhides first "31:34" and sometimes first I see "43:46" or "39:42" or "35:38". Where can be the problem? Is it better to use different macro code if I have always 4 rows to unhide step by step? I have two cases when I am unhiding rows starting from the top and another case when I am starting to unhide rows from the bottom by clicking the button. Thats why I am using macro with ranges.

```
Sub UnhideEducation()
Static counter As Byte

    counter = (counter + 1) Mod 5

    Select Case counter
        Case 1
            Rows("31:34").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case 2
            Rows("35:38").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case 3
            Rows("39:42").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case 4
            Rows("43:46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Case 5
            Rows("43:46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: This might be happening because of the static declaration.Could you tell us what exactly are you trying to do ? Alternate solution might be an easy one!

Comment: I am making CV template with "Education" section also I have "Work history" section. By pressing "ADD" button user unhides more and more options for filling in his "Education" and "Work history" background. In "Education" section rows are unhiding from the top so starting from the first place of studying reading from the top -> 2013, 2016, 2018 etc. For "Work history" section options are unhiding from the bottom so if they all would be visible "unhided" by pressing button they would look like from the top 2018, 2016, 2013, 2012. I hope you understood my bad English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about having something simpler like below and have a separate code for each button which will do hide/unhide not just hide !,

[image]

```
Sub Unhideyellow()
            Rows("34:40").EntireRow.Hidden = Not Rows("34:40").EntireRow.Hidden
End Sub
Sub UnhideGrey()
            Rows("41:46").EntireRow.Hidden = Not Rows("41:46").EntireRow.Hidden
End Sub
```